# Python Regex match everything except words that start with a hashtag

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match all the words that do not start with a hashtag using Python Regex.

Example sentence:

```
    This is #a test for #matching #hashtags
```

I would like the following to be matched: This is test for

I was able to match all the words that start with a hashtag with this: **#\b\w***

Then I realized I needed the opposite.

I tried many variation similar to these without success:

- ^(?#\b\w*)
- ^(?!#)\w+$
- ^(?!#).*
- /([\s\S]*?)(#)
- ^(?:(?!#).)*$

Nothing works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a Regex, you will need a Negative Lookbehind

`(?<!#)\b\w+`

https://regex101.com/r/aMdc7R/1

Answer (score 2):

A non-regex solution should be fine:

```py
>>> text = 'This is #a test for #matching #hashtags'
>>> [word for word in text.split(' ') if not word.startswith('#')]
['This', 'is', 'test', 'for']
```

For regex, you  need to use something like negative lookbehind assertion, which will match only if the substring is not preceded by substring/character specified.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent firing the lookbehind on every position before a match, you can switch the word boundary and the lookbehind (as lookarounds can be expensive) and the lookbehind fires after asserting the word boundary.

```
\b(?<!#)\w+
```

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?<!#)` Negative lookbehind, assert not # directly to the left of the current position
- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1HRi9h/1)