# Regex to Match Non Hashtag words in Unicode text

Tags: regex, ruby

I am struggling to write a ruby regex which can detect non hash tag words in a Unicode string. I am aware of this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68913365/python-regex-match-everything-except-words-that-start-with-a-hashtag) . This fails to detect unicode characters Live [demo](https://rubular.com/r/cx9wlpboJZCdh3)  Java’s regular expression syntax can also be appreciated .

```
Example :
Input : #bulls gonna overtake the #bears soon #ATH coming #ALTSEASON #BSCGem #eth #btc #memecoin #100xgems #satyasanata
@Prakhar #सुप्रभात आपके लिए हार्दिक शुभकामनाएं आपका दिन मंगलमय हो #GoodMorning Luv from India

O/P :  gonna overtake the soon coming @Prakhar आपके लिए हार्दिक शुभकामनाएं आपका दिन मंगलमय हो Luv from India
```

Comment: Does `/\b(?<!#)[\p{L}\p{M}\d_]+/`work for you?

Comment: Like this? `(?<!\S)[^\s#]+` https://rubular.com/r/POjmhEBMKNPip1

Comment: So, do you want to get `@Prakhar` or `Prakhar` from `@Prakhar`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew editied the question

Comment: Ok, `(?<!\S)[^\s#]+` should be the solution. Unless you have some punctuation in the strings, but you have not shown any in the sample input.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You can take it if you want, yours worked first for the first example.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Can you hint how can i convert this regex to Java's Regex syntax. thanks your solution works for my case

Comment: @PrakharNigam In Java `String regex = "(?<!\\S)[^\\s#]+";`

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew and The forth Bird , your answers really helped alot. Will try to reciprocate my wisdom for the help of community.thanks again

Comment: @Thefourthbird My top comment regex did not work, it output `Prakhar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assert a whitespace boundary to the left `(?<!\S)` and then match 1 or more characters other than a whitespace character or a `#` character using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

```
(?<!\S)[^\s#]+
```

See a [Rubular demo](https://rubular.com/r/jz3XBljgcKQmAx).